# "git stash store requires one <commit> argument" during rebase --abort

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash, git-interactive-rebase

Every time I think I'm a Git wizard some entirely new and weird thing happens to put me back in my place...

I was in the process of squashing two commits in an interactive rebase, when all of a sudden the outputs from Git started like overwriting themselves, and multiple Git Bash prompts appeared in the mess as if the commands thought they were complete before they actually were (I forgot to take a screenshot unfortunately).  My repo now seems corrupt, as I am stuck in `REBASE-i` mode and cannot abort.  Below are some screenshots that will hopefully help the more-Git-wizardry-than-I troubleshoot (`git s` is an alias for `git status`).  I have literally never seen that `Cannot store` message before, and I don't understand how it could be generated by `rebase`.  I can always delete the repo and make a fresh clone but I thought I'd appeal to SO before throwing in the towel here...

**EDIT:**
Here are the steps I took that led up to this issue:

1. `git commit --squash head` so that I could squash my latest changes with the previous commit.
2. `git rebase -i --autosquash head^^` to start an interactive rebase with the `squash` command already set up.
3. The rebase proceeded normally but then started showing the weird output described above.  It started complaining about not being able to unlink `.pack` files and if I wanted to try again.  I'd seen that message before; usually it just keeps asking to retry forever, so instead I exited with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.
4. At that point, I was unable to `git rebase --abort`, with the error message shown below.
5. I tried `git rebase --edit-todo` and deleted all lines of the todo file, but rebase continued to fail.
6. Finally I ran `git rebase --continue` and it got me out of `REBASE-i` mode, allowing me to get on with my life in a very flustered state...

**Version Info:**
 - Git for Windows: 2.18.0
 - Windows: Windows 10 Pro 1803

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: If no changes were there on current branch, that you are bothered of losing. You can do `git reset select-crash`

Comment: @ArunG Thanks for the response.  Well there are no changes because I'm rebasing.  And even if `reset` I'll still be `REBASE-i` mode

Comment: This is strange behavior. What previous steps lead to this state?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Agreed!  I edited my question to provide more of the steps leading up to those screenshots.

Comment: In that case hard reset may help. `git reset --hard <remote>/select-crash`
Note: replace <remote> with `origin` if that is the remote you have.

Comment: Again, `reset` wouldn't abort a `rebase`

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is clearly a bug and has to do with rebase's `--autostash` (probably enabled via `git config`'s `rebase.autoStash` setting).  To get more detail and debug you may need to supply your particular Git version.<sup>1</sup>  <s>What made autostash itself trigger was this:</s>

> 1. `git commit --squash head` so that I could squash my latest changes with the previous commit.
> 2. `git rebase`...

(I assume step 1 is actually `git merge --squash HEAD`.  On Windows, you *can* write `HEAD` in all-lowercase, though I believe this is a bad habit since it may suddenly stop working in the future, and does not work on some other systems.  If you dislike typing four capital lettters, consider using `@` as shorthand for `HEAD`, which does work everywhere, at least since about Git 1.8.)

Without a `git commit` in between, `git merge --squash` leaves everything uncommitted, because `--squash` always turns on `--no-commit`.  This leaves rebase in the position of being unable to start, except for the ability of `git rebase` to run `git stash` (since 1.8.4).

The preceding is wrong, per comments below, and I'm now not at all sure why the autostash code is (must be) running and getting confused.

To *do* auto-stashing, though, `git rebase` must in fact run `git stash`, and there were various bugs (one that I considered serious enough to avoid using autostash) in this until Git version 2.0.1 / 2.1.0, and further bugs fixed much more recently in 2.10 and 2.13.

(I still do not use autostash myself.  I'd rather just be reminded that I need to commit or stash before rebasing, and in general, I want to *commit* at this point.)

The unlink errors are almost certainly Windows-specific and might only be side issues.  The, or at least *a*, problem with emptying out the TODO (`git rebase --edit-todo`) was supposedly fixed in Git 2.0.1 / 2.1.0!  See the [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/29d9e3e2c47dd4b5053b0a98c891878d398463e3/Documentation/RelNotes/2.1.0.txt#L351-L354).

---

<sup>1</sup>This looks to me like a Windows version, which I won't have, although perhaps the bug can be triggered on other systems too.  I probably won't have time to dig into it myself anyway, though.

Comment: I actually did use `git commit --squash head` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---squashltcommitgt)).  I didn't realized all-lowercase `head` was a bad habit, that's good to know.  I was using Git Bash, not command prompt, if that makes any difference.  I also edited my question to include the versions of Git/Windows involved.

Comment: Oh.  Well, then `--autostash` / `rebase.autoStash` might not be the culprit. But I think it must still be, or at least still be involved in some way. BTW the concern with `head` (lowercase) is that Git currently stores all this information in flies, but this leads to issues when you, on a Windows box, fetch from Fred on a Linux box and Fred has branches named `polish` (for cleaning up) and `Polish` (for sausages) and, oops, now what. Either Git is going to start forbidding mixed-case ref-names, or these things may get moved to a database where they become case-sensitive.

Comment: Very interesting, things us oblivious Windows users don't even think about :P  I like your `@` suggestion, I'll have to start using that.  Anyway, if there is some Git mailing list or something where I should submit a bug, I'm happy to do that.

Comment: There are multiple mailing lists I think, some specifically for Windows, one for the main Git project. The Windows guys are pretty active, and Microsoft have built a lot of stuff atop Git and now care about the core technology...

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to get out of `REBASE` mode by running `git rebase --continue`, <strike>so I'm not sure what happened.  I'll wait to mark this as the accepted answer in case anybody wants to chime in with a better explanation of what happened.</strike>

See @torek's answer/comments for some additional info, though it doesn't technically provide a solution.